# No luck installing Mono 3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, mono

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on two older Dell towers and a Mac G5. After much research I got Mono 3.12.0 to install on one of the Dells but not the other one. Wanted to move my 3D printing software (which requires Mono 3+) to the G5 because it's a bit snappier.

I tried various repositories but always ended up with unmet dependencies and 'you have held broken packages'. When trying to resolve dependencies mono-runtime seems to be required which I can't find.

In the end I downloaded the Mono 3.12.1.tar from the Mono developer website. It stumbled during Make with this:

```
 CC       libmonoruntimesgen_static_la-sgen-layout-stats.lo
  CC       libmonoruntimesgen_static_la-sgen-qsort.lo
  CCLD     libmonoruntimesgen-static.la
  CC       pedump.o
  CCLD     pedump
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-loader.o): In function `mono_stack_walk_async_safe':
/home/peter/Apps/mono-3.12.1/mono/metadata/loader.c:2322: undefined reference to `mono_sigctx_to_monoctx'
/usr/bin/ld: pedump: hidden symbol `mono_sigctx_to_monoctx' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [pedump] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/Apps/mono-3.12.1/mono/metadata'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/Apps/mono-3.12.1/mono'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/Apps/mono-3.12.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't be the only one running into this problem. Sorry, I am stupid Mac guy.

Comment: Perhaps using a more recent Ubuntu release would help better in running the latest software.

Comment: @xangua: Trusty is still supported for another year.

Answer (score 0):

The Mono Project provides [instructions to install recent versions of Mono provided by Xamarin](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives):

> ### Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatives
>
> Add the Mono Project GPG signing key and the package repository to your system (if you don’t use `sudo`, be sure to switch to root):
>
> ```sh
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
> echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Run a package upgrade to upgrade existing packages to the latest available. Then install Mono as described in the [Usage](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage) section.
>
> Note: While the APT package is built against Debian Wheezy, it is compatible with a number of Debian derivatives (including Ubuntu) which means you can use the same repository across all these distributions.
>
> #### `mod_mono` (Ubuntu 13.10 and later, Debian 8.0 and later)
>
> To enable `mod_mono` installation on Ubuntu 13.10 and later, and Debian 8.0 and later (and their derivatives), you will need to add a second repository to your system, **in addition** to the generic Debian/Ubuntu repository above (if you don’t use `sudo`, be sure to switch to root):
>
> ```sh
> echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
> ```
>
> […]
>
> #### Older Ubuntu releases (Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04)
>
> To enable installation on older Ubuntu releases such as Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 (and their derivatives), you will need to add a second repository to your system, **in addition** to the generic Debian/Ubuntu repository (if you don’t use `sudo`, be sure to switch to root):
>
> ```sh
> echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libtiff-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
> ```
>
> […]
>
> ### Usage
>
> The package `mono-devel` should be installed to compile code.
>
> The package `mono-complete` should be installed to install everything – this should cover most cases of “assembly not found” errors.
>
> The package `referenceassemblies-pcl` should be installed for PCL compilation support – this will resolve most cases of “Framework not installed: .NETPortable” errors during software compilation.
>
> The package `ca-certificates-mono` should be installed to get SSL certificates for HTTPS connections. Install this package if you run into trouble making HTTPS connections.
>
> […]
>
> ### Notes
>
> After the installation completed successfully, it’s a good idea to run through the basic hello world examples on [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) to verify Mono is working correctly.
>
> Mono on Linux before 3.12 by default didn’t trust any SSL certificates so you got errors when accessing HTTPS resources. This is not required anymore as 3.12 and later include a new tool that runs on package installation and syncs Mono’s certificate store with the system certificate store (on older versions you had to import Mozilla’s list of trusted certificates by running `mozroots --import --sync`). Some systems are configured in a way so that the necessary package isn’t pulled in when Mono is installed, in those cases **make sure the `ca-certificates-mono` package is installed**.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!